# IntelIiJ bug? Class is not recognized

Tags: java, class, intellij-idea

I have created a class inside my project but IntelliJ does not recognize it as such. I had my mate create the class for me but the problem seems to persist only on my machine. I will link a print below [image]

Comment: Does `File`>`Invalidate Caches and Restart` help?

Comment: will give that a try

Comment: It did not help.

Answer (score 1):

Found this solution that worked for me:

Select required file type in top list (Recognized File Types) -- do it for "Text files" In bottom list (Registered Patterns) select undesired pattern -- "SomeFileName.java" Click on "-" (Minus) button to remove pattern from the list Repeat 1-2-3 for other undesired patterns

If desired, you can also do this manually by editing config file while IDE is closed. Because it's IDE-wide setting, it is not stored in .idea folder (which has project settinsg only) -- the file to look for is called filetypes.xml and shoudl be located in ~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdeaXX/options ( see http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181 for other OS etc )